# How to use a web proxy in a software without any support for it?

Tags: proxy, web-proxy

we have a problem on a customer network : a software cannot reach the web, but browsers run fine since they have a proxy configured. 
The software don't have any option about proxy configuration, and will not be easy to modify just for one client. How can we make it run anyway?

Maybe a web proxy installed on a local server? Another idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a proxy server in front of this software. You can then redirect the HTTP traffic to this proxy server transparently. In this case, the software will be forced to use this proxy without any other modification. This proxy server will should be configured to use the network proxy server as parent proxy.

On Linux platform, you can do this with `squid` and `iptables`.